# Can I limit the number of items going to a station via convey?

Tags: anylogic

I'm a newbie with AnyLogic, so please forgive if this is an easy question!

I have a selectoutput block. From this, if false, I want the agent to travel via a convey block to station 1 (From 'current position' to 'station1'). But before the agent goes onto the convey block to travel to station 1, I want it to check whether station 1 has more than 3 agents waiting for it (with 1 agent already in the station, so 4 total). If there are more than 3 agents waiting, I want the current agent to skip the station altogether.

I have tried adding a limit of 1 on the space markup drawn station, along with adding a queue with capacity of 3 into the flow diagram just before the convey block, but the queue does not seem to do anything at all.

TIA for any help!

[A snip of the material flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjnRF.png)

[The queue settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HHPI.png)

[The convey settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7QuS.png)

[The space markup view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7TiB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SOF.

Sounds like you simply need to add a `SelectOutput` coming between your existing `SelectOutput`'s `false` exit and the convey block. In that new one, you check how many agents are in the station and on the conveyor already. If it is more/equal than 4, you bypass it, else you make the agent convey there.

You can also play with the `Restricted Area Start/End` blocks that "cordon off" and area of your flow if too many agents are inside (check the help). But for bypassing, you would still need another `SelectOutput` block.

cheers

Comment: Thank you - That sounds like exactly what I need!

Comment: great. if this was helpful, please mark my reply as "useful" (small up arrow on the left). This will mark the answer as "resolved" and help others find this faster if they have similar problems in the future :-)